# How to keep a strong reference around?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I am wrapping AVAudioPlayer with a very simple class that allows me to specify and url and immediately play it and then call a completion block, like this:

```
[AudioPlayer playAudioWithURL:url
                  completionBlock:^{
                      //finished playing
                  }];
```

Reason why I wrote this is because it's very easy, simple. No need to implement delegate, etc...Problem is, this won't work. Doing this in a function will obviously allocate it on stack and it will be de-allocated soon, causing the sound to stop playing.

So, what's the best way to implement this kind of wrapper, to keep a reference around until the sound is finished playing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any problem. What makes you think that it "will obviously allocate it on stack and it will be de-allocated soon"? Have you tried it? You obviously don't have a good understanding of how memory management in Objective-C works.

In your implementation of `playAudioWithURL:urlcompletionBlock:`, you will inevitably have some kind of asynchronous dispatch. This dispatch will inevitably have to retain your audio player object, in order to have it play stuff. So no, it won't get deallocated, unless you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how possible this would be using ARC since you can't really manage the retain/release cycles. I've done something similar to this using a wrapper for `UIAlertView`, and what I have done -- not using ARC, of course -- would be to simply to call `[self retain]` on the wrapper class during the `show` method and then, when the delegate method is called on the wrapper, call the `completionBlock` and then `[self release]`. This guarantees (so long as you're following retain/release rules!) that the wrapper class will be alive at least until the callback is called and, in the usual case, the wrapper will suicide itself once it's done doing its job. Again, since you can't manage retain cycles using ARC, I'm not sure if this will work.

The alternative for you might be to look into simply subclassing `AVAudioPlayer` or creating a category version of it, setting the delegate to itself. That may be able to keep it alive long enough for it to persist until the full sound plays -- though I am a bit fuzzy on how ARC works.

Best of luck!